# Wordpress/woocommerce : Redirect when user is logged in causing Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've found 3 codes here and tried them all. The codes are to redirect logged in users to home.com/shop

And they do work... However when I use it the error is triggered when order is being placed (Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

The code I'm using is

```
    function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(40583) ) {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pagid),
            site_url()
        );
        wp_redirect(site_url('/shop'));
        exit;
        }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have this issue when you checkout.
Normally checkout process is ajax.
So you need to check whether current process is ajax or not.

Please try following code.

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(40583) && !wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pagid),
            site_url()
        );
        wp_redirect(site_url('/shop'));
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

Comment: I think you are correct. that's what I get in network tab ?wc-ajax=checkout I'll check your code right away...

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! It does work now!!! You're awesome man